# Android Emulator Screen Corruption when drawing

Tags: android, android-studio, android-drawable

I have an android app that seems to run ok on my Samsung Galaxy S7 Edge, but when i fire up the emulator for a PIXEL 2, when i redraw the background it becomes corrupted. Here is a screenshot and code if anyone has any ideas. I tried calling invalidate() on the view, but that doesnt help either. Here is a  [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U7tlH.png)

```
     public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,boolean fromUser) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            redValue=progress;
            String colorvalue = "Red: " + redValue + " Green: " + greenValue + " Blue: " + blueValue + " Brightness: " + brightValue  + " Saturation: " + satValue;
            progressTextView.setText(colorvalue);
            int[] color = returnRGB(redValue,greenValue,blueValue);
            progressTextView.setTextColor(Color.rgb(color[0],color[1],color[2]));
            hueValue = getHue(color[0],color[1],color[2]);
            String hexColor = String.format( "%02x%02x%02x%02x",255, color[0], color[1], color[2]).toUpperCase();
            int decimalcolor = (int) Long.parseLong(hexColor, 16);
            int [] gradientColor = new int[4];
            gradientColor[0]= startColor; //these values will be changed by the slider
            gradientColor[1]=decimalColor;
            gradientColor[2]=decimalColor;
            gradientColor[3]=endColor;
            background = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, color);
            background.setGradientType(GradientDrawable.RADIAL_GRADIENT);
            background.setGradientRadius(returnGradientRadius(brightValue));
            background.setGradientCenter(0,0);
            background.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
            background.setColors(gradientColor);
            backgroundView.setBackground(background);
            submitButton.setBackground(background);
        }
    });
```

When I adjust the seek bar in the image below, you can see the corruption. This doesn't happen on my live device, but whats the point of testing it on an emulator if it doesn't accurately simulate a real world device? Or is it possible that this does not work on a live Pixel 2? What am I missing?

Comment: are you using hardware acceleration? (and if so.. is your emulator set up for this?)

Comment: HAXM is installed. I have tried setting the hardware acceleration to both software and hardware, and tried using both the GLES 2.0 and 1.1 compatibility options. Is there anything else I am missing or you could recommend i try?

Answer (score 0):

Try running the app on some other devices.
It's likely to be problem with emulator.
You can also change settings for graphics processing on emulator.
Change it to use your gpu, not to simulate Pixel's.